# Proving or Refuting Time Complexity

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory

I have an exam soon and I wasn't at university for a long time, cause I was at the hospital

Prove or refute the following statements:

1. log(n)= O(
   √
   n)
2. 3^(n-1)= O(2^n)
3. f(n) + g(n) = O(f(g(n)))
4. 2^(n+1) = O(2^n)

Could someone please help me and explain to me ?

Answer (score 1):

(1) is true because log(n) grows asymptotically slower than any polynomial, including sqrt(n) = n^(1/2). To prove this we can observe that both log(n) and sqrt(n) are strictly increasing functions for n > 0 and then focus on a sequence where both evaluate easily, e.g., 2^(2k). Now we see log(2^(2k)) = 2k, but sqrt(2^(2k)) = 2^k. For k = 2, 2k = 2^k, and for k > 2, 2k < 2^k. This glosses over some details but the idea is sound. You can finish this by arguing that between 2^(2k) and 2^(2(k+1)) both functions have values greater than one for k >= 2 and thus any crossings can be eliminated by multiplying sqrt(n) by some constant.

(2) it is not true that 3^(n-1) is O(2^n). Suppose this were true. Then there exists an n0 and c such that for n > n0, 3^(n-1) <= c*2^n. First, eliminate the -1 by adding a (1/3) to the front; so (1/3)*3^n <= c*2^n. Next, divide through by 2^n: (1/3)*(3/2)^n <= c. Multiply by 3: (3/2)^n <= 3c. Finally, take the log of both sides with base 3/2: n <= log_3/2 (3c). The RHS is a constant expression and n is a variable; so this cannot be true of arbitrarily large n as required. This is a contradiction so our supposition was wrong; that is, 3^(n-1) is not O(2^n).

(3) this is not true. f(n) = 1 and g(n) = n is an easy counterexample. In this case, f(n) + g(n) = 1 + n but O(f(g(n)) = O(f(n)) = O(1).

(4) this is true. Rewrite 2^(n+1) as 2*2^n and it becomes obvious that this is true for n >= 1 by choosing c > 2.

Comment: @Hamza07 Which one? At least (4) should be easy enough to follow if you are familiar with the definition of big-Oh. if you're not familiar with that definition, you need to be to have any hope of answering questions like these.